# How can I receive data from Arduino?

Tags: java, android, serial-port, arduino

I want to receive the digital pin value of 1 (high) or 0 (low) from an Arduino via the serial port.

I am unable to read any data with the following code:

```
byte[] bbuffer = new byte[1];

try {
    mInputStream.read(bbuffer);
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    new Exception("Arduino-Board antwortet nicht! Timeout!!");
}

if (bbuffer[0] == (byte)1){
    PinValue.setText("HIGH");
}
else if (bbuffer[0] == (byte)0){
    PinValue.setText("LOW");
}
```

Comment: please be careful with code formatting.  I have fixed it for you this time

Answer (score 0):

You don't give the relevant infos in your question: How do you setup the `InputStream`?

But your code show some flaws nevertheless:

> mInputStream.read(bbuffer);

The general contract of `InputStream.read` is, that you must *also* check the return value of `read`. If `read` returns a zero or a negative number, the contents of `bbuffer` is untouched.

> new Exception("Arduino-Board antwortet nicht! Timeout!!");

You only *create* a new exception, but you don't throw it. You must add `throw` to that line.